How to infer the type of an object and extend it with a type provided via generics in TypeScript?
I am trying to create a function in TypeScript that takes an object as an argument and infers its type, then combines that inferred type with another type provided via generics. The result should be an object that has the properties of both the inferred type and the generic type.
Here is what I want to achieve:
function addType<E extends object>(obj: any): // inferred object type + E {
  // Implementation
}

const x = addType<{ extraProp: number }>({ someProp: 1 });

// The type of x should be:
// {
//   someProp: number;
//   extraProp: number;
// }

The goal is to have TypeScript infer the type of the obj parameter (in this case, { someProp: number }) and then merge it with the generic type { extraProp: number }, so that the resulting type is:
{
  someProp: number;
  extraProp: number;
}

However, I want to achieve this by only providing one type argument ({ extraProp: number }), not two. I want the function to infer the type of the obj parameter automatically.
I've tried using intersection types, conditional types, and other approaches, but I keep running into issues where TypeScript either expects two type arguments or does not infer the type correctly.
Is there a way to achieve this in TypeScript without manually specifying the inferred type?

I think this will eventually lead to microsoft/TypeScript#10571

Please [edit] the question to include an example implementation of the addType function in order to clarify why a generic type parameter is needed — why it cannot be directly annotated in the return type or inferred from the implementation.

The use case is a store in which part of its state is defined on a PHP server and then serialized to the client, so it is necessary to add the types of the state that was initialized on the server. The best DX would be if people could infer the types of the parts that are declared on the client side, and only type the parts initialized in PHP.

You want ms/TS#26242 (which is also 10571 and others). Without it, you just need to work around it, either by currying (the answer below) or what I call "dummying", as shown in the linked q/a.  Neither one is wonderful. Currying is usually cleaner.

It feels like you might be mixing types (compile time) with objects/values (runtime). If your function only takes one generic parameter, that must be the one of the object that you want to infer. You are not passing a second argument for the extra properties. This means that inside the function the extra properties must be hardcoded. If that is the case then you don't need to use types ar all for the extra props:
function addType<T extends object>(obj: T) {
  return {
    ...obj,
    extraProp: 1
  }
}

const x = addType({ someProp: 1 });
console.log(
  x.extraProp,  // OK
  x.someProp // OK
);

If you want to merge objects at runtime you can use this:
function mergeFactory<T extends object> (extra: T) {
  return <T extends object> (obj: T) => {
    return {
    ...obj,
    ...extra
  }
  }
}

// Create a new function
const addType = mergeFactory({ extraProp: 1 });


// Use the new function
const x = addType({ someProp: 1 });


console.log(
  x.extraProp,  // OK
  x.someProp // OK
);

Playground demo
To merge types, you can use &:
type Extra = { extraProp: number };
type Base = { someProp: number };

type Merge = Extra & Base;

// You can also use generics but is an overkill
type GenericMerge<T1, T2> = T1 & T2;
type Merge2 = GenericMerge<Extra, Base>;


Yeah, I had already arrived at the solution of the curried function. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, since the addType function cannot be a curried function.
function addType<E extends object>() {
  return <T extends object>(obj: T): T & E => obj as T & E;
}

const x = addType<{ extraProp: number }>()({ someProp: 1 });


Also, hardcoding the extra types doesn't work for me since these are defined by the developer.
Ultimately, the last option doesn't work for me either because what I'm looking for is to save the developer from having to explicitly declare the types of the object passed to the function.
Thanks anyway!

I think you need to provide more details. Show the implementation of addType also who implements addType? I can only see addType working in two possible ways: one of the objects is hard coded, or the two objects are parameters.

The use case is a store in which part of its state is defined on a PHP server and then serialized to the client, so it is necessary to add the types of the state that was initialized on the server. The best DX would be if people could infer the types of the parts that are declared on the client side, and only type the parts initialized in PHP.

I don't fully understand why a higher order function curried as you mention would not work. As far as I can tell it seems like a good solution. For ts it should work, or do you just prefer not to have a hof?

It works, but it's not the ideal DX.
